# Kion signifas fini demandon per "do"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, questions

Ekzemploj: "Kaj kio do?" – "Al kiu do?" – "Kial do?"

[Tekstaro](http://tekstaro.com/) donas pli ol 100 similajn rezultojn por la serĉesprimo `" do\?"`

Comment: Do = Therefore. Mi ne scias kiel klarigi esperante, sed rigardu tion: http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/do.html#do.0

Comment: @Lumo5 Ĝi ne signifas ‘therefore’ en ĉi tiu kunteksto.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mi pensas, ke tio estas nur por emfazo. Ĝi estas simila al la angla ‘(So) [question] then?’. Ekzemple, en la angla, viaj ekzemploj estus:

*Kaj kio do?* = And what then?
*Al kiu do?* = So to whom then?
*Kial do?* = So why then?

Krome, en PIV estas menciite, ke “tiu uzo [de *do*] povas servi, en okazo de dubo, por neprigi la demandan sencon de la korelativoj”. Vidu [do senco 2](http://vortaro.net/#do).

Answer (score 3):

Vidu en vortaro.net:

- Do: uzata en demandaj aŭ ordonaj frazoj, por insisti pri la miro aŭ la volo