# How do you say "so what?" in Esperanto?

Tags: phrase-requests

When someone tells an unimpressive story, one can impolitely respond with a question indicating that one would expect the story to go on.

> A: "I won against my little brother in chess"
>
> B: "So what?"

How do you say this in Esperanto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In that situation I would probably say something like:

*Kaj kio? Ĉu eĉ gravas?*

Comment: Or for a shorter expression: *Ĉu gravas?*

Answer (score 2):

I found 39 hits in the tekstaro for the search term `Kio do\?`

Kio do = So what

Comment: Sole existence in Tekstaro may easily be deceptive here. Based on the answers to my [earlier question](http://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/2531/kion-signifas-fini-demandon-per-do) I'm quite sure this means something different, like "what then?". That would actually show interest, quite opposite to what the OP intends here.

Comment: I considered *kiel do" before posting my response. I checked the Tekstaro, checked PIV, checked the answers in the question on Stack Exchange about "kiel do" - and concluded that *kiel do* is the wrong answer. (If I'm wrong about all this and it's actually a good answer, then the people upvoting this answer should probably be voting to close it as a duplicate).

Comment: I considered *kiel do* before posting my response. I checked the Tekstaro, checked PIV, checked the answers in the question on Stack Exchange about "*kiel do*" - and concluded that *kiel do* is the wrong answer. (If I'm wrong about all this and it's actually a good answer, then the people upvoting this answer should probably be voting to close it as a duplicate).

Comment: @La Vo-o: The same expression can have opposite meanings (be anauto-antonym). In particular, "That's okay." can indicate acceptance or rejection.